# Loading a Workflow Instance causes an InstanceLockedException

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I'm implementing functionality to attempt to cancel a workflow instance that is currently in an executing state.  I'm using the .NET Cancel() method for a WorkflowApplication, but first I believe I'm required to Load the instance:

```
wf.Load(id);
```

then

```
wf.Cancel();
```

With the Load method, I get an InstanceLockedException.  There is only one workflow host - which in this case is a windows Service running locally on my machine.  I believe the instance is locked by the workflow service ... is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

If the workflow is in an executing state then you have already loaded it.

Try wf.Cancel(); on the instance you have executing.